# how to remove SVT AV1 information from FFMpeg output

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I can't find how to remove SVT AV1 information, like the ones I report below, from the FFMpeg output.

Command :

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -loglevel error -hide_banner -stats -hwaccel auto -i .\in.mp4 -c:V libsvtav1 .\out.mp4 -y

.\ffmpeg.exe : Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
In riga:1 car:1
+ .\ffmpeg.exe -loglevel error -hide_banner -stats -hwaccel auto -i .\K ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Svt[info]: ----...---------------:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Svt[info]: SVT [version]:   SVT-AV1 Encoder Lib v1.4.1-103-g72fd3d47
Svt[info]: SVT [build]  :   GCC 12.2.0   64 bit
Svt[info]: LIB Build date: Mar 19 2023 14:58:25
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[info]: Number of logical cores available: 8
Svt[info]: Number of PPCS 102
Svt[info]: [asm level on system : up to avx]
Svt[info]: [asm level selected : up to avx]
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: main profile   tier (auto) level (auto)
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: width / height / fps numerator / fps denominator       : 1920 / 1080 / 30 / 1
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: bit-depth / color format                   : 8 / YUV420
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: preset / tune / pred struct                    : 10 / PSNR / random access
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: gop size / mini-gop size / key-frame type          : 161 / 32 / key frame
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: BRC mode / rate factor                     : CRF / 35 
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What Operating System? What shell? Please [edit] and add appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.8.0/Source/Lib/Common/Codec/EbLog.c#L31
https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.8.0/Source/Lib/Common/Codec/EbLog.h#L18

This is controlled by `SVT_LOG` environment variables (INFO by default), values are:

```c
typedef enum {
    SVT_LOG_ALL   = -1,
    SVT_LOG_FATAL = 0,
    SVT_LOG_ERROR = 1,
    SVT_LOG_WARN  = 2,
    SVT_LOG_INFO  = 3,
    SVT_LOG_DEBUG = 4,
} SvtLogLevel;
```

To print only errors, use (for bash/zsh shell):

```bash
export SVT_LOG=1
```